# How can I make the sidebar of a page scroll out the main body content on display

Tags: javascript, html, tailwind-css

**Problem Description**

My problem is this, I have a sidebar, that is positioned 66% offscreen using -translate-x-2/3. So it is hanging there until the onmouseover event which pulls the sidebar out.
All is good, that is however, the main body content is stuck in the one spot. It seems to me that the flex class I have them under is treating the sidebar content as if it's always taking up the initial width of x-3/12 and not responding to the fact that I am then translating the sidebar offscreen.

**Images for context**

[Unused Space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OBeV.png)

[Sidebar Extended](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2CzI.png)

**Code**

***HTML***

*index.html*

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="h-screen overflow-hidden flex items-center justify-center" style="background: #edf2f7;">
        <div class="flex flex-wrap bg-gray-100 w-full h-screen">
            <!-- Sidebar -->
            <div class="w-3/12 h-full bg-white rounded p-3 shadow-lg transform -translate-x-2/3 transition duration-500 ease-in-out"
                id="pid" onmouseover="displayShow()">
                <div class="flex items-center space-x-4 p-2 mb-5">
                    <img class="h-12 rounded-full"
                        src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/2acfb745ecf9d4dccb3364752d17f65f?s=260&amp;d=mp"
                        alt="James Bhatta">
                    <div>
                        <h4 class="font-semibold text-lg text-gray-700 capitalize font-poppins tracking-wide">James
                            Bhatta</h4>
                        <span class="text-sm tracking-wide flex items-center space-x-1">
                            <svg class="h-4 text-green-500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none"
                                viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                                <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
                                    d="M9 12l2 2 4-4m5.618-4.016A11.955 11.955 0 0112 2.944a11.955 11.955 0 01-8.618 3.04A12.02 12.02 0 003 9c0 5.591 3.824 10.29 9 11.622 5.176-1.332 9-6.03 9-11.622 0-1.042-.133-2.052-.382-3.016z">
                                </path>
                            </svg>
                            <span class="text-gray-600">Verified</span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <ul class="space-y-2 text-sm">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"
                            class="flex items-center space-x-3 text-gray-700 p-2 rounded-md font-medium hover:bg-gray-200 bg-gray-200 focus:shadow-outline">
                            <span class="text-gray-600">
                                <svg class="h-5" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                                    stroke="currentColor">
                                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
                                        d="M9.75 17L9 20l-1 1h8l-1-1-.75-3M3 13h18M5 17h14a2 2 0 002-2V5a2 2 0 00-2-2H5a2 2 0 00-2 2v10a2 2 0 002 2z">
                                    </path>
                                </svg>
                            </span>
                            <span>Dashboard</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"
                            class="flex items-center space-x-3 text-gray-700 p-2 rounded-md font-medium hover:bg-gray-200 focus:bg-gray-200 focus:shadow-outline">
                            <span class="text-gray-600">
                                <svg class="h-5" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                                    stroke="currentColor">
                                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
                                        d="M15 17h5l-1.405-1.405A2.032 2.032 0 0118 14.158V11a6.002 6.002 0 00-4-5.659V5a2 2 0 10-4 0v.341C7.67 6.165 6 8.388 6 11v3.159c0 .538-.214 1.055-.595 1.436L4 17h5m6 0v1a3 3 0 11-6 0v-1m6 0H9">
                                    </path>
                                </svg>
                            </span>
                            <span>Notifications</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"
                            class="flex items-center space-x-3 text-gray-700 p-2 rounded-md font-medium hover:bg-gray-200 focus:bg-gray-200 focus:shadow-outline">
                            <span class="text-gray-600">
                                <svg class="h-5" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                                    stroke="currentColor">
                                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
                                        d="M7 8h10M7 12h4m1 8l-4-4H5a2 2 0 01-2-2V6a2 2 0 012-2h14a2 2 0 012 2v8a2 2 0 01-2 2h-3l-4 4z">
                                    </path>
                                </svg>
                            </span>
                            <span>Personal messages</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"
                            class="flex items-center space-x-3 text-gray-700 p-2 rounded-md font-medium hover:bg-gray-200 focus:bg-gray-200 focus:shadow-outline">
                            <span class="text-gray-600">
                                <svg class="h-5" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                                    stroke="currentColor">
                                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
                                        d="M16 7a4 4 0 11-8 0 4 4 0 018 0zM12 14a7 7 0 00-7 7h14a7 7 0 00-7-7z"></path>
                                </svg>
                            </span>
                            <span>My profile</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"
                            class="flex items-center space-x-3 text-gray-700 p-2 rounded-md font-medium hover:bg-gray-200 focus:bg-gray-200 focus:shadow-outline">
                            <span class="text-gray-600">
                                <svg class="h-5" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                                    stroke="currentColor">
                                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
                                        d="M12 6V4m0 2a2 2 0 100 4m0-4a2 2 0 110 4m-6 8a2 2 0 100-4m0 4a2 2 0 110-4m0 4v2m0-6V4m6 6v10m6-2a2 2 0 100-4m0 4a2 2 0 110-4m0 4v2m0-6V4">
                                    </path>
                                </svg>
                            </span>
                            <span>Settings</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"
                            class="flex items-center space-x-3 text-gray-700 p-2 rounded-md font-medium hover:bg-gray-200 focus:bg-gray-200 focus:shadow-outline">
                            <span class="text-gray-600">
                                <svg class="h-5" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                                    stroke="currentColor">
                                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
                                        d="M12 15v2m-6 4h12a2 2 0 002-2v-6a2 2 0 00-2-2H6a2 2 0 00-2 2v6a2 2 0 002 2zm10-10V7a4 4 0 00-8 0v4h8z">
                                    </path>
                                </svg>
                            </span>
                            <span>Change password</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"
                            class="flex items-center space-x-3 text-gray-700 p-2 rounded-md font-medium hover:bg-gray-200 focus:bg-gray-200 focus:shadow-outline">
                            <span class="text-gray-600">
                                <svg class="h-5" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                                    stroke="currentColor">
                                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
                                        d="M17 16l4-4m0 0l-4-4m4 4H7m6 4v1a3 3 0 01-3 3H6a3 3 0 01-3-3V7a3 3 0 013-3h4a3 3 0 013 3v1">
                                    </path>
                                </svg>
                            </span>
                            <span>Logout</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="flex-grow" id="mainContent">
                <div class="p-4 text-gray-500">
                    Content here...
                    <div class="inline-flex">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        function displayHide() {
            document.getElementById("pid").classList.add("-translate-x-2/3");
        }
        function displayShow() {
            document.getElementById("pid").classList.remove("-translate-x-2/3");

        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Do you want the content of your page to be displaced when the sidebar is opened and closed?

Comment: @Jarne Kompier
The sidebar starts closed, I would like the content to reflect that.
As in, the content uses the unused space when sidebar is closed.
Then when sidebar is opened, the content will be displaced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue.

**Description of my solution.**
After I had a little think about it, the solution I came up with initially, was to set the sidebar to an absolute position. What this done for me, was allow me to get the entire page width from x=0 -> x=MAX. I then used transform and translate to move the contents along at the exact same moment as the sidebar, giving that nice effect of the page moving along as the side bar expanded. I also instantiated the contents translated to the exact location which the sidebar was hidden. If you look in my screenshots you can see what I mean when the sidebar is hidden, it is extended only 6.25%. So I translated the contents + 6.25% also. Which means 6.25% of the contents scroll OFF the right side of the page, JUST AT INSTANTIATION, very unresponsive.

I really disliked this solution. In some use cases, It can give a nice effect, which results in THE ENTIRE RIGHT SIDE OF THE CONTENTS being scrolled out of view. I think I may use this method in the future with some cases, it looks nice, but not if you want contents to be responsive. I plan on using a navbar, and having to design a navbar always with a -6.25% padding really jiffed me.

To make a more responsive design. What I done, was included a div class behind the absolute positioned sidebar. That would seat itself infront of the main content and because the parent of this div is `flex` then the content would perfectly sit by it's side.

```
            <div class="transition-width w-1/16 duration-700 ease-in-out md:bg-gray-200 md:shadow-2xl" id="behindSidebar"></div>
            <div class="flex-grow transform transition duration-500 ease-in-out" id="mainContent" onmouseover="displayHide()">
```

When the sidebar is hovered over then `displayShow()` Is called, when the main content is hovered over then `displayHide()` Is called.

Here is all the code for the working solution from initial problem

**Javascript**

```
        function displayHide() {
            document.getElementById("sidebar").classList.add("md:-translate-x-3/4");
            document.getElementById("sidebar").classList.add("-translate-x-full");
            document.getElementById("behindSidebar").classList.remove("w-1/4");
            document.getElementById("behindSidebar").classList.add("w-1/16");
        }
        function displayShow() {
            document.getElementById("sidebar").classList.remove("-translate-x-full");
            document.getElementById("sidebar").classList.remove("md:-translate-x-3/4");
            document.getElementById("behindSidebar").classList.remove("w-1/16");
            document.getElementById("behindSidebar").classList.add("w-1/4");
        }
```

**Sidebar**

```
<!-- THIS DIV CLASS IS WHAT WAS CHANGED!!!!! -->
<div class="overflow-hidden absolute w-1/4 h-full bg-white rounded p-3 shadow-lg transform -translate-x-full md:-translate-x-3/4 transition duration-500 ease-in-out" id="sidebar" onmouseover="displayShow()">
<!-- NO OTHER CHANGES!!!!! -->
    <div class="flex items-center space-x-4 p-2 mb-5">
        <img class="h-12 rounded-full" src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/2acfb745ecf9d4dccb3364752d17f65f?s=260&amp;d=mp" alt="James Bhatta">
        <div>
            <h4 class="font-semibold text-lg text-gray-700 capitalize font-poppins tracking-wide">James Bhatta</h4>
```

**Contents**

```
            <!-- This div sits behind the Sidebar, it has a longer delay to give a nice fade out effect -->
            <div class="transition-width w-1/16 duration-700 ease-in-out md:bg-gray-200 md:shadow-2xl" id="behindSidebar"></div>
            <!-- End -->
            <div class="flex-grow transform transition duration-500 ease-in-out" id="mainContent" onmouseover="displayHide()">
                <div class="p-4 text-gray-500">
                    Content here...a
                    <div class="inline-flex">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**IMPORTANT!**
If you are going to implement this solution, please be aware, using tailwindcss you must include
**tailwind.config.js**

```
  theme: {
    extend: {
      "translate":
      {
        '1/16': '6.25%',
        '-1/16': '-6.25%',
      },
      width:
      {
        '1/16': '6.25%',
        '-1/16': '-6.25%',
      },
      transitionProperty:
      {
        'width': 'width'
      },
    },
  },
```

If anyone has any more thoughts or comments on a better solution, I'm all ears, this is the way I came up with, since the main content has flex-grow. It automatically resizes itself according to the space left on the page due to the resizing div box.
Thanks.